# How can I avoid passing a parameter to each function but still have access to it inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the button, I am opening a Jquery dialog and creating an object of CustomClass. I need this object in different functions. Is there a way to avoid passing it to each function but still have access to it inside the function?

Note: I am using the same code to open multiple dialogs through different click events.

**JS Fiddle Link**: https://jsfiddle.net/gwphxssq/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div class='btn1'>Button1</div>
<div class='btn2'>Button2</div>
<p class='plain-text'> Two dialog's open, one behind the other. Please drag the top dialog to see the other dialog below.
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
var Test = Test || {};
Test = {
  CustomClass: function(fnSave) {
    return {
      dialogElem: null,
      saveBtn: null,
      fnSave: fnSave
    }
  },
  Cache: function(obj, dialogElem) {
    obj.dialogElem = $(dialogElem);
    obj.saveBtn = $(dialogElem).find('.btnSave');
  },
  OpenDialog: function(option) {
    var that = this;
    var dynamicElem = '<div>Dialog' +
      '<input type="button" class="btnSave" value="Save"/>' + '</div>';

    var obj = new that.CustomClass(option);

    $(dynamicElem).dialog({
      open: function(event, ui) {
        that.Cache(obj, this);
      }
    });

    //obj is being passed to different functions. How can I avoid passing  it to each function but still have access to the obj in each of the functions below?

    that.BindEvents(obj);
    that.SampleFunc1(obj);
    that.SampleFunc2(obj);
  },

  BindEvents: function(obj) {
    obj.saveBtn.on('click', function() {
      obj.fnSave();
    });
  },
  SampleFunc1: function(obj) {
    //Need the obj here too
    //Some code
  },

    SampleFunc2: function(obj) {
    //Need the obj here too
    //Some code
  }
}


//Click Event for Button 1
$('.btn1').on('click', function() {

  Test.OpenDialog(function() {
    alert('First Dialog');
  });
});

//Click Event for Button 2
$('.btn2').on('click', function() {

  Test.OpenDialog(function() {
    alert('Second Dialog');
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn1,
.btn2 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.plain-text {
  color: red;
}

.btnSave {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using an actual class or old-school JS constructor function? If you did that your other functions could be methods defined on the prototype and automatically get access to the new object via `this`.

Comment: Simply declare the object in a scope reachable by every function that needs it. Global scope can generally be avoided but use it if you must.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have made the changes. Please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/gwphxssq/10/. Is this what you were suggesting? I cant use class as I have to support IE11.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Tried it using a different approach. Please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/gwphxssq/10/. Let me know your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a factory which creates new functions, and those functions have the object in their closure. For example:

```
OpenDialog: function (option) {
    var that = this;
    var dynamicElem = '<div>Dialog' +
       '<input type="button" class="btnSave" value="Save"/>' + '</div>';
    var obj = new that.CustomClass(option);

    var fxns = that.createFxns(obj);

    fxns.bindEvents();
    fxns.sampleFunc1();
    fxns.sampleFunc2();
},
createFxns: function(obj) {
    return {
        bindEvents: function () {
            obj.on('click', function () {
               obj.fnSave();
            }
        },
        sampleFunc1: function () {},
        sampleFunc2: function () {}
    }
}
```

I don't see that you get much out of this pattern though. The main benefit of this is that you could pass those functions around to some other piece of code, and have the object already 'baked in'. That way the other piece of code doesn't even need to know that obj exists. In your case though, you're just calling them right away, and your class clearly needs to know about the existence of obj.

Comment: Tried it using a different approach. Please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/gwphxssq/10/. Let me know your inputs.